# Prevent INSERT of NULL values for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I'm working on a stored procedure that is supposed to update a table `Order_TruckDelivery` with info from another table `Basket_TruckDelivery` if the second table has any data. There are two columns in each of the tables: an `int` `id` and a `datetime` column called `TruckDeliveryDate`. If `Basket_TruckDelivery` has a date stored for the current basket id, then insert that date into the `Order_TruckDelivery` table.

Right now, the `INSERT` will execute regardless if there is anything in the `Basket_TruckDelivery` table, and this results in a NULL value for the `TruckDelveryDate` column in the `Order_TruckDelivery` column. I want to prevent this from happening but am not entirely sure how. Basically, I only want to perform and `INSERT` into the `Order_TruckDelivery` table IF the value of `TruckDeliveryDate` in `Basket_TruckDelivery` is NOT empty or null.

This is what I have so far...I have not done much work with stored procedures, so I am not sure what I've missed....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveTruckIntoOrder]
    @BasketID INT, 
    @OrderID INT
AS
BEGIN
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE
      @TruckDeliveryDate DATETIME

   IF(EXISTS(SELECT uidBasket FROM [Basket_TruckDelivery] WHERE [uidBasket] = @BasketID))
   BEGIN 
        SELECT
            @TruckDeliveryDate = [TruckDeliveryDate] 
        FROM 
            [Basket_TruckDelivery] 
        WHERE 
            [uidBasket] = @BasketID
   END

   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO [Order_TruckDelivery] ([uidOrder], [TruckDeliveryDate])
       VALUES (@OrderID, @TruckDeliveryDate)
   END
END
```

Comment: It appears that the END And BEGIN statements between the SELECT and INSERT statements should not be there.  The INSERT statement is always being run because of that.

Comment: Just use anotehr IF for INSERT checking FOR blahDATE IS NOT NULL

Comment: Mihai, that is apparently all I needed...everything seems to work just fine now.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveTruckIntoOrder] @BasketID INT
    ,@OrderID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TruckDeliveryDate DATETIME

    IF (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT uidBasket
                FROM [Basket_TruckDelivery]
                WHERE [uidBasket] = @BasketID
                )
            )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TruckDeliveryDate = [TruckDeliveryDate]
        FROM [Basket_TruckDelivery]
        WHERE [uidBasket] = @BasketID
    END

    IF (
            @TruckDeliveryDate IS NOT NULL
            AND @TruckDeliveryDate != ''
            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Order_TruckDelivery] (
            [uidOrder]
            ,[TruckDeliveryDate]
            )
        VALUES (
            @OrderID
            ,@TruckDeliveryDate
            )
    END
END
```